# Finding an equation that results in a specific integer, Python

Tags: python

I am attempting to do today's [intermediate challenge](http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/2qxrtk/20141231_challenge_195_intermediate_math_dice/) on r/dailyprogrammer, and I'm at a loss for how to do the actual meat of the problem: finding the right operands so that the sum of the "scoring dice" numbers results in the number from the target die.  The only way I can think of doing it is to bruteforce it.  For example, finding what operands would make the sum of 2 4 6 8 and 10 equal 16.

By the way, this is the code I have so far:

```
# r/dailyprogrammer, Intermediate #195

import random

def dice_roller(dice, sides):
    '''Takes the number of dice and the number of sides, and returns a list of values accordingly.'''
    if dice == 1:
        return random.randint(1, sides)
    else:
        rs = []
        for i in dice:
            rs.append(random.randint(1, sides)

        return rs

def math_dice(td, sdc):
    '''Math dice game.  Both parameters should be in that dice notation format, like 1d20 and 4d6.'''
    try:
        target_number = dice_roller(td.split('d'))
        equation_numbers = dice_roller(sdc.split('d'))
    except:
        return ValueError
```

I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: Brute forcing the solution, though there are only two possible signs (+/-) for each number, could still take a long time. I think it's O(2^n) where n is the number of solution dice, but that's assuming there's a solution using all the dice. It's much larger if not. You would have to search 2 + 2^2 + ... + 2^(n-1) + 2^n, whatever that series sums to.

Comment: I think it's +/0/-, so the brute-force solution would be O(3^n)

Comment: @mbomb007 Wouldn't it still be `O(2^n)` as that term would dominate the others?

Comment: Actually, it would be `2^(n+1) - 2`.

Comment: @NayukeMinase I see where you're coming from, and you may be right. My series in the above comment is wrong, since the excluded numbers have to be tested, then try excluded the same amount of different numbers. So it'd be O(3^n). Also, @YatharthROCK the `- 2` wouldn't affect the big oh. It'd just be O(2^(n+1)), except we just determined I was wrong. Also, that's not even what the sum would've been.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subset sum problem. Partial answer using brute-force recursion.

Let's use the example in the problem statement: target = 9, dice = [1, 3, 1, 3, 5].

We can solve this problem recursively by only examining the first dice in the list in each function call.

Let's look at the first number, 1.

- If we use this die as a positive number, then the remaining target is 8 and dice are [3, 1, 3, 5].
- If we use this die as a negative number, then the remaining target is 10 and dice are [3, 1, 3, 5].
- If we skip this die, then the remaining target is still 9 and dice are [3, 1, 3, 5].

In each of these three scenarios, we recurse and apply the same logic. And the base of the recursion when there are no dice, the query is successful if and only if the target is 0 (because an empty sum is 0).

Here it is in Python code:

```
# target is an integer, dice is a list of integers, equation is a string
def solve(target, dice, equation, sum):
    if len(dice) == 0:
        if target == 0:
            print equation + " = " + str(sum)
    else:
        first = dice[0]
        solve(target - first, dice[1 : ], equation + " + " + str(first), sum + first)
        solve(target + first, dice[1 : ], equation + " - " + str(first), sum - first)
        solve(target, dice[1 : ], equation, sum)

# Example:
solve(9, [1,3,1,3,5], "", 0)
# Prints:
 + 1 + 3 + 5 = 9
 + 1 + 3 + 5 = 9
 - 1 + 3 - 1 + 3 + 5 = 9
 + 3 + 1 + 5 = 9
 + 1 + 3 + 5 = 9
```